# Add Allauth login_required decorator to Baton.Autodiscover Admin subclass

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-baton

I'm using [Django-Baton](https://github.com/otto-torino/django-baton), which injects CSS and JS styles and utilities around core Django template files, along with [Django-AllAuth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more robust authentication and account access features.

I'm using the [documented method](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=login_required(admin.site.login)#admin) to redirect admin login to the AllAuth login page:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login)
```

Which I'm supposed to apply to "every instance of AdminSite."

URLs:

```
from baton.autodiscover import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("", admin.site.urls),
    path("baton/", include("baton.urls")),
    path("integrations/", include("integrations.urls")),
    path("queryfilter/", include("core.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
]
```

Without `baton.autodiscover`, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` forwards, as desired, to `accounts/login`, but not so with autodiscover present.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "dal",
    "dal_select2",
    "dal_queryset_sequence",
    "baton",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",  # required for allauth
    "users",
    "core",
    "integrations",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "baton.autodiscover",
]
```

Wondering if I need to subclass `django.contrib.admin` and apply the auth decorator somehow prior to `baton.autodiscover`, but not sure how/where to do it.

Thanks for your input, and I'm pretty new to Django so thanks also for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django.contrib.admin.AdminSite` is a parent class of `baton.autodiscover.admin`([source](https://github.com/otto-torino/django-baton/blob/master/baton/autodiscover/admin.py)).

You have to decorate `baton.autodiscover.admin` in `urls.py`.

URLs:

```
from baton.autodiscover import admin
from django.urls import path, include

admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", admin.site.urls),
    path("baton/", include("baton.urls")),
    path("integrations/", include("integrations.urls")),
    path("queryfilter/", include("core.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
]
```